# Skype Sorry we didn't recognise your sign in details

Tags: skype

I have problems connecting to skype. Details:

1. I can connect ok by **Skype Web** (see image 1)
2. I can not connect through **Skype Desktop for Windows 10** (see image 2)
3. I have already **reinstalled** the product twice, cleaned the **registry** and the corresponding **folder**
4. It is installed to the **latest version** (see image 3)
5. I think that maybe the MAC address of my computer or the serial number of my disk are **blocked**. But I do not know if it's the cause.
6. Firewall is disabled. No proxy.

It is **not a credential problem** because I can connect on the web.

Can you help me?

Error message: **"Sorry we didn't recognise your sign in details"**.

[image: Skype Web]

[image: Skype Desktop]

[image: Skype Version]

Comment: Be sure you are using your Microsoft Account credentials instead of your legacy Skype credentials.  The Skype screenshot indicates your attempting to use the legacy Skype username.  Of course non-English screenshot can't be read, so I might be mistaken, but either way seems like a Microsoft Support problem.

Comment: I uses both credentials... I do not know how to ask for microsoft support. Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved with a new serial number for my hard disk using the tool Volumen ID. You can download here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sysinternals/downloads/volumeid

This is the command (need a reboot):

```
volumeid <driveletter:> xxxx-xxxx
```